# stopUpdatingLocation cannot stoping the location update in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have been using the location class as a delegate class and using my AppDelegate to update the location. I need the location on two cases: first at the time when he first signed into my application and then the next case is when he come from background. I am using `UILocation` like this in the first case:

```
    locationController = [[UILocation alloc] init];
    locationController.delegate = self;
    locationController.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationController.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and in the second case simply:

```
[locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]
```

in my delegate method:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
```

In my delegate class I am doing this:

```
[locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

after taking the lattitude and longitude. But it still updates after calling this.

I tried

```
    locationController.locationManager=nil;
    locationController.locationManager.delegate=nil
```

after stopping the update. But after this when I call startUpdateLocation, my delegate method is not called. Can anybody point me in what I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you setup 

    locationController.locationManager=nil;
    locationController.locationManager.delegate=nil; 

Just simply call stopUpdatingLocation and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably not in the other code you provided. It is possible that you intialize `locationController` twice, this way you leak a `CLLocationManager` that keeps on updating as it does not receive the `stopUpdatingLocation` message. You should use the debugger to figure this out. Also, placing log messages in strategic points of the code is very helpful.

To avoid such double initializations, ensure that such value assignments are happening only in the `init` method.

Comment: (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
    }
    return self;
} what is wrong with this???

Comment: The code in your post does not correspond to anything like this :)